# Can people lose reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Lets say someone works hard and asks on-topic questions to gain a high reputation, then when they achieve that, they troll around the whole site. Can they lose reputation because of this?

Comment: What are your plans? Is this a warning? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is "Yes". The negative rep from downvotes goes straight into your rep.

Nonetheless, given that a downvote is -2 whereas an upvote is +10 (answer) /+5 (question) /+15 (accept) it takes much longer to loose all that rep than to gain it. Almost certainly you'll just be banned before you get down to 1.  For an example, see [this question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/many-new-user-accountsanswerssuspensions-and-protected-questions).

One note: on [[ee.meta]](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com) there is no reputation separate from [[ee.se]](http://electronics.stackexchange.com). The same is not true of [[so.meta]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), which has its own rep, being kind of the ubermeta for all stackexchange sites.

Comment: I'd like to add that one cannot have a negative/zero reputation. New users start with 1, when they get downvotes, they do not loose their 1 rep.

Comment: Don't forget bounties.

Comment: Of course skyler wouldn't know that because he's *never* been dowvoted on anything.